Difference between ndarray.data and ndarray.ctypes.data?
I have a C array, which I want to use from Python. The following C++ function uses pybind11 to expose the C array as a raw memory buffer:
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

py::memoryview create_cpp_owned()
{
  const double *dynamic_c_array = new double[4]{0, -1.2, 3.24, 9.0};
  std::cout << "Memory address of the C array: " << dynamic_c_array;
  return py::memoryview::from_memory(dynamic_c_array, sizeof(double) * 4);
}

I can then use the create_cpp_owned function from Python as follows (raw_data is a memoryview object).
print('Creating a direct accessor to a C++ buffer (memory owned by C++)...')
raw_data = create_cpp_owned()
print(f'Address of the raw data: {raw_data}') # or: print(hex(id(raw_data)))
np_view = np.frombuffer(raw_data, dtype=np.float64)
print(f'NumPy view on this data: "np_view" = {np_view}')
print(f'Address of "np_view": {hex(np_view.ctypes.data)}')
print(f'Note that np_view.data does not return the same address: {np_view.data}')
print(f'Python does not own the memory: np_view.flags["OWNDATA"] = {np_view.flags["OWNDATA"]}')

The output is
Creating a direct accessor to a C++ buffer (memory owned by C++)...
Memory address of the C array: 0x55af59d39590
Address of the raw data: <memory at 0x14a9af19f640>
NumPy view on this data: "np_view" = [ 0.   -1.2   3.24  9.  ]
Address of "np_view": 0x55af59d39590
Note that np_view.data does not return the same address: <memory at 0x14a99f3aa280>
Python does not own the memory: np_view.flags["OWNDATA"] = False

As you can see, np_view.data didn't return the correct address of the underlying C array, while np_view.ctypes.data did.
So what do .data and .ctypes.data really represent for a NumPy array?

The id (or print name) of a memoryview does not show its memory address.

@hpaulj Why not? In CPython (what I use), id gives the memory address of the object according to the documentation.

There's a difference between a memoryview object, and underlying memory if references.  https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memoryview.html

You are right, I forgot about it. Can you also answer the question at the end?

I haven't used ctypes.  As for arr.data, it can be used as the buffer parameter of a np.ndarray constructor.  There may be other low level uses.

Indeed, .data is a memoryview object, while .ctypes.data is an integer: the address of the underlying memory it references. If you write an answer, I can accept it.
